# What's wrong with my indoor Areca palm with leaf blight?

Tags: indoors, leaves, fungus, palm, scale

I just received a small areca palm (about three feet high) in the mail that has some leaves showing signs of stress. Could someone help me identify the culprit? I'm wondering whether I could address the problem myself (inexperienced with Areca palms) or whether it's too diseased to salvage? If this plant is beyond repair, should I contact the nursery and try to get a healthier one?

I'm also wondering whether this palm might infect my other houseplants with scale or fungus? I have a nice pothos, aloe plant, peace lily, rosemary, cilantro, and mint in the same room.

All advice would be *greatly* appreciated!

Thank you!

[image: Example of leaf damage on new arrived areca palm]

[image: Leaf blight on areca palm]

[image: Is this scale?]

[image: Is this normal on the base?]

Comment: If you only just received it, I'd definitely return it - the marks on the stems aren't much to worry about, but some of the leaves show damage and leaf spotting. Not what I'd expect from a newly bought plant...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback. I'll probably return it. It was from the American Plant Exchange. Disappointing!